# Clojure targeted initially to servers?

Tags: java, clojure

Since Clojure is designed to run in a Java virtual machine (JVM), I don't understand [this statement](https://nightweb.net/blog/clojure-on-android.html):

> While Clojure started its life mainly as a server-side language, the advent of ClojureScript demonstrates that the core developers don't see that as its only purpose.

I am not real familiar with Java though I am interested in Lisp languages and hence Clojure, so this makes me wonder. Most web servers I've worked on are traditional Apache variants with standard server-side languages like Ruby, PHP, Perl, but I've never seen Java as a default installed server language in my hosting environments, so what is the meaning of this statement?

Second, JVMs are typically run on client operating systems like Mac or Windows, are they not? Sun says there are many billions of JVMs in the world, obviously this is not referring to servers.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [wikipedia for JavaEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition), that might give you an insight into the enterprise side of Java.

Comment: While the use of Java on end user machines has declined for many years, it continues to grow on servers, and far outstripped home Java use many years ago, at least in terms of actual use and likely in terms of install base as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is exactly as much of a server-side language as Ruby or Perl (though not really PHP): It's a general-purpose language that is frequently used to write server applications, including Web applications and SOA services. Whether Java is "installed as a default", it's typically trivial to install on the Unix machines that are the usual hosts for Java servers.

A JVM can theoretically run on any platform; there are JVMs that run on bare x86 hardware, and Blu-Ray players have embedded JVMs. Sun originally thought that Java was the future for rich-client applications, but instead it's found a much wider use in powering Web sites and other services that clients access through various APIs.

Answer (score 3):

One main point is that Clojure has several important philosophies and practices that, when applied to a particular runtime environment such as the JVM, JavaScript/ECMAScript, etc. yield a powerful language. These philosophies include:

- simplicity: The ability to [separate distinct parts](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy). All the clojure variants provide for the separation of Code and data. This includes the ability to deal with data independently of the code that produced it. Directly this is the ability to read and write compound and simple (non-comound) data structures is built into the language.
- [Immutable Data Structures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ketJlzX-254): All Clojure varients have data structures where producing a new version of even a very large data structure is efficient, and leaves the old data intact. If you pass a large data structure to several threads there is no need for locking because they work on different "forks" of the data. This is all done without copying (with structural sharing) and is efficient.
- Explicit handling of [Identity, State and Time](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey): All the Clojure Varients provide explicit handling of sequences of events built into the languge. This is different between variants depending on the platform. For instance ClojureScript which produces JavaScript as it's output has no place for coordinated syncronous updates because JavaScript has only one thread, though it has all the rest of the types.

There is a lot more and it can be found on the [Clojure Philosophy Page](http://clojure.org/rationale). It is also worth mentioning that If not the majority, then a very large part of the worlds web applications are written almost entirely in Java. Many people find that Clojure provides them a way to interact with this world, even if Java isn't their preferred language.

Answer (score 1):

By `server-side` language the author does not mean just the web server. It may include a whole stack of services running on the server from simple file upload to big data processing, served  to the clients via the web.

`Second, JVMs are typically run on client operating systems like Mac or Windows, are they not?`

JVM is a development as well as deployment platform. There are numerous web scale applications deployed over JVM. It is very common to have JVM installed on you servers if your stack includes java based services.

Comment: +1, I would hazard a guess that there are more CPU cycles of server side JVMs being churned at any given moment than client side CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The author of that statement means that Clojure was envisioned as a server-side language, but it has enough power where there is a demand to be able to use Clojure on the client as well.

An important distinction though is that it isn't like Clojure is actually running in a browser. ClojureScript is a tool that compiles client-side (i.e. browser) Clojure code into JavaScript. It is similar to CoffeeScript, which compiles Ruby-style code into JavaScript.

So ClojureScript is nothing more than syntactic sugar that lets people who love the power and succinctness of Clojure on the server side still write Clojure on the client side in the browser. But in the end, that client-side Clojure isn't really Clojure at all but JavaScript.

So when it comes to ClojureScript, the JVM is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Clojure's history, but it seems clear that it has been intended as a general-purpose language for some time--whatever initially pushed Hickey et al. to want to develop it.  Because Clojure supports easy access to existing Java libraries and is able to create standard Java-style jar files--both crucial benefits on a server as well as elsewhere--it would have been obvious early on that Clojure could be useful outside of servers.  So my answer to why "the advent of ClojureScript demonstrates that the core developers don't see [server side applications] as its only purpose" is that no such demonstration was needed.

Comment: Because clojure has a high startup overhead, and relatively extreme RAM usage overhead even before you start loading your own app's code, it is better suited for a long running task that restarts rarely, and serves large numbers of clients before shutting down. This is not just because of the JVM, it also has to do with the introspection and redefinition capabilities of the clojure language preventing many space and startup time optimizations.

Comment: Thanks @noisesmith.  That makes some sense.  I do find that clojure starts slowly, especially using Leiningen.  I agree that it's not ideal for things that need to get going quickly, that repeatedly start up often, or that are started interactively on slower systems such as some phones and small notebooks.  Not all client applications fall into those categories ([example](http://www.stat.osu.edu/~lkubatko/software/STEM)), but many do.